# Convolve application

Tags: convolution

How to define the function 
$$f_m(s)=\begin{cases}
s^m, \quad s\in[0,n]\\
0, \quad otherwise
\end{cases}$$

And to get its value of discrete self-convolution in $s=n$ by means of `Convolve` function ? My try:

Let be function `f[m_, s_, n_]` defined as follows:

```
f[m_, s_, n_] := 0
f[m_, s_, n_] := s^m /; 0 <= s <= n
s = n; Sum[f[2, s - k, n]*f[2, k, n], {k, -Infinity, +Infinity}]
```

and result is always zero, which is not supposed to be

Comment: I don't understand your definitions; the first one pretty much makes the function identically zero everywhere. What did you mean by it? Are there conditions on the values of $m$, $s$, $n$?

Comment: Thats the point, i need to present the expression $\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^m(n-k)^m$ in terms of convolution of power function defined on finite interval [0,n]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be straightforward if you use Piecewise to define f:

```
f[s_, n_, m_] := Piecewise[{{s^m, 0 < s < n}, {0, True}}]
Convolve[f[s, 3, 2], f[s, 3, 2], s , t]
```

This returns a plausible Piecewise expression.

Comment: I think you are doing a continuous convolution, while the question specified a discrete convolution.

Comment: Yes, exactly, im sorry that haven't noticed that it should be discrete convolution

Comment: by the way, now the entry `s = n = 4; Sum[f[2, s - k, n]*f[2, k, n], {k, -Infinity, +Infinity}]` gives correct result 34, but still let's try to make it more beautiful using native method Convole :)

Answer (score 2):

The right function to use is `DiscreteConvolve[]`; in addition, use `UnitStep[]` to impose your finite conditions:

```
DiscreteConvolve[UnitStep[k] k^m, UnitStep[k] k^m, k, s]
```